# Extract and rename to numeric ID

Tags: regex, powershell

I'd like to rename files through PowerShell if the last part of the filename ends in `'_<some number>.<extension>`

For example, given the following files:

```
Houseplants_1083982.jpg
Pottery_2304.jpg
Astral Projection 3.jpg
Photography - TOC.xml
```

The desired output would be:

```
1083982.jpg
2304.jpg
Astral Projection 3.jpg
Photography - TOC.xml
```

What regex do I need for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex and use `$1` as replacement

```
.*_(\d+\.[a-z][a-z0-9]+)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nS2jY9/3)**

Comment: Thank you. I like that this captures the case of `Houseplant_123.45.jpg` even though I didn't specify it :D

Comment: @Katie you are welcome..that was obvious because you wanted only number after `_`

Answer (score 1):

Single line version `^.*_(\d+\.[^.\\]+)$`

```
 ^ .* _
 (                             # (1 start)
      \d+ 
      \. [^.\\]+ 
 )                             # (1 end)
 $
```

Or, multi-line version `(?m)^.*_(\d+\.[^.\\\r\n]+)$`

```
 (?m)
 ^ .* _
 (                             # (1 start)
      \d+ 
      \. [^.\\\r\n]+ 
 )                             # (1 end)
 $
```

Replace with `$1`